# android autocompletion with google play services version 6: view viewEnd

Tags: android, google-search, android-app-indexing

This [tutorial](http://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/app-indexing#8) clearly shows how to record page view start and end with google play services version 7+. I am forced to use version 6 with does not have start and end methods. I have gotten autocompletion to work with the version 6 API, but I am not sure if I am losing some functionality with these different methods.

Where the linked tutorial uses [start](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appindexing/AppIndexApi), I am using [view](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appindexing/AppIndexApi):

```
PendingResult<Status> view(GoogleApiClient apiClient, Activity activity, Uri appUri, String title, Uri webUrl, List<AppIndexApi.AppIndexingLink> outLinks)
```

Where the linked tutorial uses [end](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appindexing/AppIndexApi), I am using [viewEnd](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appindexing/AppIndexApi):

```
PendingResult<Status> viewEnd(GoogleApiClient apiClient, Activity activity, Uri appUri)
```

Aside from not being able to set a description with view/viewEnd, is there any functional difference between start/end vs view/viewEnd?

Comment: offtopic comment: problem with links : [viewEnd](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/appindexing/AppIndexApi.html#viewEnd(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.net.Uri))  works ... the problem were spaces in the link ... which could be replaced with %20

Answer (score 1):

If autocompletion works for you, using view and viewEnd is fine.

Cheers,

MB

Comment: What is this based on?